# More complicated Excel formulas in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way that more complicated calculations can be made using textboxs in vb.net

Below is an example formula from Excel which relies on the calculation of A4 divided by A3 to achieve the correct number before subtracting A5. In vb.net i would want to substitute the cell references from the formula with textboxs (or other entry fields)

**=SUM(SUM(A4/A3)-A5)/SUM(A4/A3)**

Any ideas would be appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Are you actually talking about parsing an arbitrary math expression and calculating the result in your own VB.NET code?

Comment: Yes, basically i want to replicate, for example, the formula above and convert into code. Thanks

Comment: AH, your formula appears to be bogus. e.g. SUM(A4/A5) should most likely be SUM(A4:A5). The first instances is the sum of A4 divided by A5, which doesn't make sense. A4:A5 is a range that is passed to SUM().

Comment: No its not, the formula is correct it basically reads that the value in A4 needs to be divided by the value in A3 **BEFORE** it has the value of A5 subtracted. That value is then **Divided** by the total value of A4 divided by A3

Comment: I think you need to remove the SUM() calls first. My note above show be for A4/A3 not A4/A3.) Maybe =((A4/A3)-A5)/(A4/A3) Assuming you have textboxes with the same names you can add .Text: ans = ((A4.text/A3.text)-A5.text)/(A4.text/A3.text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a Try ... Catch ... Block around the code as a minimal defense against not all boxes containing numbers or zeros.

```
        Try
            ans = ((A4.text/A3.text)-A5.text)/(A4.text/A3.text)
        Catch
            msgbox ex.message
        End Try
```